# If A and B are hermitian matrices then can we prove or disprove that

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ and $B$ are hermitian matrices then can we prove or disprove that $\lambda_{max}(A+B)$ $\leq$ $\lambda_{max}(A)$+$\lambda_{max}(B)$ where $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue of the corresponding matrices.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Do you know about norms on matrices?

Comment: yes i have read about it.

Comment: ohh yes!!! i have got the solution thanks for the suggestion, this statement is true for hermitian case.